# Find out Excel column character from name of cell in first row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have an excel sheet that looks like this;

[image]

The header names are found in first row. I would like to have a VBA function that returns the column number, given the cell name in the first row. For example, getColumnNumber("B Symbol") should return `B`. getColumnNumber("C Symbol") should return `C`.

I am using Excel 2016.

Comment: You want column number or column character ? Since your post says column number, but in your example you want to get B, so which one ?

Comment: Column character. Sorry, wrong choice of word in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the text and then read the address.

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:z1") ' 
    Set c = .Find("whatever you need to find", lookin:=xlValues) 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = split(c.Address,"$")(0) 
        msgbox firstAddress 
    End If 
End With
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel

Comment: Thanks for answer. Upvoted. What if I only want to find the text in the first row? Oops. I read your code carefully and it does what I want.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-rows-property-excel `Worksheets(1).Rows(1)` Search google. all of it is there:)

Comment: teddy2, a slight modification required for your answer. `firstAddress = split(c.Address,"$")(0) ` should be `firstAddress = split(c.Address,"$")(1)`. Otherwise, your answer is perfect. Anyway, I have marked your answer as correct. Please make the necessary change. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA for this. The following formula works just as well and any VBA is using essentially the same method.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, MATCH("C Symbol", 1:1, 0), 4), 1, TEXT(,))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to my own question, modified from teddys'. There is a slight error in his answer.

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:z1") ' 
    Set c = .Find("whatever you need to find", lookin:=xlValues) 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = split(c.Address,"$")(1) 'should be 1, not 0 
        msgbox firstAddress 
    End If 
End With
```